# HTML/CSS Spacer (like Flex's)

Tags: html, css, apache-flex

I've been wondering if there is any technique to use HTML/CSS like Flex/MXML. I mean, in MXML the HBox, VBox and Spacer are globally used, and their behavior is predictable. But in HTML/CSS we use a lot of float and it always have some 'hidden surprises'.

With Flex/MXML I would do:

```
<hbox width="100%">
    <button label="Button A" />
    <spacer width="100%" />
    <button label="Button B" />
    <button label="Button C" />
</hbox>
```

- If you don't know flex I explain this code: the HBox places every element inside it side by side, and the Spacer is an invisible element; the spacer with 100% does not have the same width as the parent (HBox) but it fills the remaining space; this means that A will be aligned to the left, and the two other to the right.

Now in HTML/CSS I would make buttons B and C float to the right. I also would have to reverse the order of the buttons to the final result be the same. Besides, I probably would put some blank tag with "clear:both" to ensure that nothing below will be messed up.

So, is there any technique to obtain the same functionality in HTML/CSS? That would be fantastic if we could make .HBox .VBox .Spacer CSS classes and without javascript.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Flex uses 'spacers'? Eww. ('spacers' as described are a rather antiquated way of dealing with HTML layout. Sad/surprised/maybe not that surprised that Flex uses them)

Comment: You are probably right. But with HTML+CSS its way more nasty, eg: float should be used only for images with text around it. I wrote the code to achieve the same result of the text above, check http://jsfiddle.net/wEAay/1/ Isn't MXML code much more clean and objective?

Comment: Spacers break the MVC structure of HTML, CSS, and JS.

Comment: @Eric.Void quite the contrary. A spacer isn't content...so doesn't even belong in the xml/html...hence the benefits of CSS.

Comment: Well, the point I was trying to get is that (besides the conceptual controversy of the spacer) MXML is very straight forward and predictable. And within HTML/CSS (besides its power) one must tame and dominate more or less all the tricks and workarounds. 

Finaly my question: Is there any way to overcome all those tricks and workarounds of HTML/CSS to make it more objective and under control?

Answer (score 2):

I do something similar to this using the following kind of markup

```
<div class="formline"><!-- kind of like your hbox -->
    <div class="buttongroup" id="group1">
        <button label="Button A"> <!-- of course, that's usually input type="submit" or something. -->
    </div>
    <div class="buttongroup" id="group2">
        <button label="Button B">
        <button label="Button C">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use CSS to style it.
I'd float group1 to the left, float group2 to the right. The enclosing formline contains the floating within it.  The buttons appear in the correct order, I don't have to reverse them.

This is all logical/structural markup and can be styled different ways; it's not there just for presentation.

I use sensible names depending on what I'm doing, not things like "group1", "group2".

Comment: @Eric - I looked at your fiddle, that's essentially what I do. I don't need the extra empty div just because, in our form structures, every "formline" is followed by _something_ else that can have the `clear: both` cleanup. "formline" itself has the clear, and the most common case for us is a formline followed by another formline.

Comment: Our solutions are the same ha. A funny but good rule of thumb in HTML/CSS is that if it doesn't work add more divs. Which sounds terrible but kinda works. If you want to keep your syntax light you could use JS to replace parts of your page.

Answer (score 1):

You could give your top level div a class named hbox and target its sub items. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/soparrissays/WJ2Lk/4/ 
html:

```
<div class="hbox">
    <input type="button" value="Button A" class="left-button" />
    <input type="button" value="Button C" />
    <input type="button" value="Button B" />
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

style:

```
.hbox {
    margin-top:45px;
}

.hbox input {
    float: right;
}

.hbox .left-button{
    float:left;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

[image: button on the left, 2 on the right] Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I think the * is breaking things. You don't need to float the br. Here is the new fork i made: http://jsfiddle.net/soparrissays/WJ2Lk/. I also posted a picture in my answer above. It could help if you posted a picture of what you wanted it to look like as well. Button works as does input just so you know.

Comment: Eric wants side-by-side left/right with a gap between, not stacked. The `<spacer>` in Flex provides a "flexible space" that expands as needed to fill the line and push its siblings to the left and right.

Comment: Also, the reason floats are powerful and used frequently is so that the page will adjust nicely for various browsers widths and such. Alternative approaches include fixed/absolutely positioned styles (but that isn't a good solution for an entire website if you ask me. The other option is to use styles entirely created by javascript. That really isn't a bad solution either.